# How to do scroll down effect(slide down) when click on top navigations..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to do that scroll effect(slide down) when click on top navigations..?

[Example Website](http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_411_dragonfruit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return true;
    });
```

use this jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that I created it uses jQuery. So Make sure you have jQuery included on your HTML page.

```
var NCRscroll = function(){
     var animateScroll=function(e,t,n,r){r=r||-60;n=n||2e3;$(e).on("click",function(){$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(t).offset().top+r},n);return false})}
     /* 
        NCRScroll has four parameters link that users click on (link). Id is to where on the page you want to scrollTo (id).
        Speed is the speed at which the scroll feature goes to the section of the page that you desire.
        The default value for speed is 2000 milliseconds which is 2 seconds. So it doesn't have to be set if you like the speed.
        The last parameter is the offset which is defaulted to -60.  You can change this to your desire. -60 work in this template.
      */
      //Demo of how your call should look.
      animateScroll("#showcaselink", "#showcase", 1000, 20);
  };
```

Then just call the function.

`NCRscroll();`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Parent</a>
        <ul class="childnav">
            <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.childnav {
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}

li.dropdown:hover ul.childnav {
    display:block;
}
```

I'm sure a simple web search would have given you something just like this.